# How to extract this data point from this code?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have this CSS line and I would like to extract the percentage **87.19%** that comes after style=width using R.

`<div class="ei_meter_bar" style="width:87.19%"</div>`

Here's what I have thus far:

```
webpage <- read_html(url)
ei <- html_nodes(webpage,'.ei_meter_bar')
ei_data <- html_text(ei)
```

I hope to get an output of 87.19%.

Comment: @akrun thank you! This solves my issue. I was also wondering if you know how to scrape an interactive webpage for that specific css line. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `parse_number`

```
readr::parse_number(str1)
#[1] 87.19
```

---

If we need the `%` also

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str1, "[0-9.]+%")
#[1] "87.19%"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- '<div class="ei_meter_bar" style="width:87.19%"</div'
```